# Want to increase only Jquery dialog height with bit of animation

Tags: jquery

i use jquery animate function to increase height & width of jquery dialog. it is working but i need to increase only height not width with bit of animation.

i wrote the code like

```
$("#dialog").animate({ height: $content.outerHeight(), width: $content.outerWidth() }, 1000,
             function () {
                 $("#dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles");
                 $content.fadeIn('slow'); 
             });
```

but animate function take two parameter height & width but i need to increase only height. so is there anything similar like jquery animate function by which i can increase height only.
please help...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of animate in this example is an object which represents the key/value pairs of the css properties you want jquery to animate to. So in your example you are saying animate the width AND height to these sizes. You can give that object as many or as little key/value css pairs as you would like. So for you the below example should work

```
$("#dialog").animate({ height: $content.outerHeight() }, 1000,
             function () {
                 $("#dialog").removeClass("BusyStyles");
                 $content.fadeIn('slow'); 
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to put only height, those are optional properties

http://api.jquery.com/animate/